# How to add array values into dropdown list using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

i'm splitting the string **;#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#**  with VBA code

```
      Sub Splitfn()

         Dim str As String
         Dim var As Variant
         Dim i As Long

       str = ";#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#"
       var = Split(str, ";#")
       For i = 0 To UBound(var)
       Debug.Print i, var(i)
      Next i    
      End Sub

  That returns 
  0            
  1            WR_1
  2            WR_2
  3            WR_3
  4            WR_4
  5
```

I want to add these values(WR_1,WR_2,WR_3,WR_4) to dropdown list. How to specify that in VBA code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combo boxes accept strings as a value list:

```
sStr = ";#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#"
 ''      Var = Split(Str, ";#")
sStr = Replace(sStr, "#", "")
Me.Combo9.RowSourceType = "value list"
Me.Combo9.RowSource = sStr
```

The first value will be empty, because the first character is the delimiter `;`, if this is not required, it is easy to change:

```
sStr=Mid(sStr,2)
Me.Combo9.RowSource = sStr
```

Comment: WoW it works. Thank you for prompt reply!! It shows all 4 items but the first item is showing blank or empty space how to remove the first item

Comment: As I said, this is because you have a delimiter as your first character, you can use Mid to strip it: `sStr=Mid(sStr,2)`